# Detect blemish spot in an image for iphone Application

Tags: iphone, ios5, core-image

How can I detect and fined blemish of an `image` and correct it ?
is there any sample code available?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, if you mean to remove the blemish before using a picture you can allways use Photo Blemish Remover. Dont know why you are looking for sample code. Just clean the image and use the improved one. 
There is a demo you could try from Aviary iOS SDK found: [Right HERE](http://www.aviary.com/ios-documentation)

[Photo Blemish Remover](http://www.photo-toolbox.com/download/download.php?target=free_photo_blemish_remover_win_x86_cnet)